# Mapping a POCO Class to MVC Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, poco

I am new to MVC as well as EF. Following some Nice Tutorials I finally created my POCO Classes.

I am trying to create a MVC Model with the help of POCO Classes in a layered architecture. Where My POCO class sits in Class Library project called `Entities`.

And my MVC4 application is a `Web` Project which references Entities.

I query database and have content in Entities and want to map 3-4 POCO classes to a single Model so i can create a strongly typed view.

Am not sure how to proceed. Assist me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [ASP.NET MVC in Action book.](http://www.manning.com/palermo3/). It has an entire chapter dedicated to this topic.  They suggest and show how to use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to map domain entities to ViewModels.

I also have an example [here](https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/feedtracker).

In the BootStrapper:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Building, BuildingDisplay>()
                .ForMember(dst => dst.TypeName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BuildingType.Name));
```

In the controller:

```
  public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var building = _db.Buildings.Find(id);

            if (building == null)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Building not found.";
                return View("NotFound");
            }

            var buildingDisplay = Mapper.Map<Building, BuildingDisplay>(building);
            buildingDisplay.BinList = Mapper.Map<ICollection<Bin>, List<BinList>>(building.Bins);

            return View(buildingDisplay);            
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @derek. Is there any online links for quick check out.Ordering may take time which i ll do.

Comment: https://github.com/jeffreypalermo/mvc2inaction/tree/master/src look at the source for chapters 2 & 3

Comment: Thanks @Derek. All links are Source Codes. Do we have any Explanation on this ?

Comment: Basically you create view models to model your screen then map the needed entitiy or entities to the view model.  AutoMapper is handy for that.

Answer (score 2):

i have answer such type of question once before, if you want to see it , here is the link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432246/creating-a-mvc-viewmodels-for-my-data/15436044#15436044
```

But inform me back if you need more help :D
here is your viewmodel

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="* required")]
    [Display(Name="Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Now for mapping use projection in linq;

```
public List<CategoryViewModel> GetAllCategories()
{
    using (var db =new Entities())
    {
        var categoriesList = db .Categories
            .Select(c => new CategoryViewModel() // here is projection to your view model
            {
                CategoryId = c.CategoryId,
                CategoryName = c.Name,
                CategoryDescription = c.Description
            });
        return categoriesList.ToList<CategoryViewModel>();
    };
 }
```

now your controller;

```
ICategoryRepository _catRepo;
    public CategoryController(ICategoryRepository catRepo)
    {
        //note that i have also used the dependancy injection. so i'm skiping that
        _catRepo = catRepo;
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //ViewBag.CategoriesList = _catRepo.GetAllCategories();
           or
        return View(_catRepo.GetAllCategories());
    }
```

And lastly your view;

```
@model IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <h1>@item.CategoryName</h1>
}
```