# Create List with anonymous objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

What I try is add some dummy records which I want to use in an ASP.NET MVC 3 view to provide data for some experiments. I try this:

```
var dummyData = new[]
            {
                new  {Row = 1, Col = 1, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "Yes?", FieldValue = "int"},
                new  {Row = 1, Col = 2, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "Yes?", FieldValue = "int"},
                new  {Row = 2, Col = 1, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "No?", FieldValue = "string"},
                new  {Row = 3, Col = 1, IsRequired = false, QuestionText = "No?", FieldValue = "string"}
            }.ToList();
            ViewBag.Header = dummyData;
```

However when I try to use the data in my view :

```
@{
          foreach (var item in ViewBag.Header)
          {

              <tr><td>@item.QuestionText</td><td>@item.FieldValue</td></tr>

          }
       }
```

I get this error - `'object' does not contain a definition for 'QuestionText'`. I'm thinking that there's something wrong with the way I create the list but not 100% sure.

Comment: I would advise you do not rely on anonymous objects and the view bag so much. Things are much better when they are strongly typed

Comment: Related...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-sharp-anonymous-type-objects     I would suggest using a Tuple class.

Comment: why don't you use viewmodel instead?

Comment: see my this example of creating viewmodel => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432246/creating-a-mvc-viewmodels-for-my-data/15436044#15436044

Comment: I'm learning on the fly. Have to check what exactly `viewmodel` can do for me here, and also I have previous experience with Windows Forms application where we vastly use anonymous objects and it was perfectly fine so I just decided to follow this line.

Comment: @DotNetDreamer While that may be a better practice it really has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: @JaceRhea, that's why i put it in comments. It was suggestion. If you like it go ahead use it otherwise i have no complain about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An anonymous type is local to the scope from which it was declared.  You are not going to easily be able to get properties off it outside the scope of the type declaration.  [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-sharp-anonymous-type-objects).

I would suggest using a Tuple or just create a simple POCO object for the data.

```
var dummyData = new[]
        {
            Tuple.Create(1, 1, true, "Yes?", "int"),
        }.ToList();
        ViewBag.Header = dummyData;
```

Comment: Not what I really wanted but closest to some solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dummyData = new List<dynamic>
        {
            new  {Row = 1, Col = 1, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "Yes?", FieldValue = "int"},
            new  {Row = 1, Col = 2, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "Yes?", FieldValue = "int"},
            new  {Row = 2, Col = 1, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "No?", FieldValue = "string"},
            new  {Row = 3, Col = 1, IsRequired = false, QuestionText = "No?", FieldValue = "string"}
        };
        ViewBag.Header = dummyData;
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `foreach` definition to this:

```
@{ foreach (dynamic item in ViewBag.Header) {
```

the problem is that they are anonymous classes so they need to be used as `dynamic` classes so the CLR can late bind the object at runtime.