# Am I mixing up controller / model in this MVC implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

New to MVC, so forgive the question.

I have created two models, `Observation` and `StaffMember`.  An observation is carried out by a staff member and I record the Id of the StaffMember (GUID) against the Observation record.  When displaying the results I wish to show the `StaffMember.FullName` rather than `StaffMember.StaffMemberId`.

I have managed to achieve this by using the following model:

```
public class Observation
{
    public Guid ObservationId { get; set; }
    public string Observer { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime ObservationDate { get; set; }
    public Guid StaffMemberId { get; set; }
    public int? ObservationGrade { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<StaffMember> StaffMembers { get; set; }

    public string StaffMemberName
    {
        get
        {
            var db = new ObservationTrackerContext();
            var staffMember = db.StaffMembers.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StaffMemberId == StaffMemberId);

            return staffMember != null ? staffMember.FullName : "Missing entry or error";
        }
    }
}
```

I am a little concerned that I am mixing up the definition of the model with the database interactions. Is this a correct use of the MVC pattern or should I be doing this in a different way?

Thanks in advance for any comments or suggestions.

Comment: Controllers have nothing to do with database interactions. In the MVC pattern, they're part of the "model". That said, the model is usually more than the data structure / entity classes - frequently there's a "data access" or a "business logic" layer that does the data manipulation, and the controller just picks which business logic action to run.

Comment: That said, the `StaffMemberName` property is iffy - it involves running database access code after the `Observation` entity was already retrieved. If nothing else this is inefficient. Generally you should try to have your controller fetch data structures where you just navigate to the needed data that is already loaded, for example by using [`Include()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696785(v=vs.103).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are referring to this last part:

```
public string StaffMemberName
    {
        get
        {  var db = new ObservationTrackerContext();
            var staffMember = db.StaffMembers.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StaffMemberId == StaffMemberId);    
        return staffMember != null ? staffMember.FullName : "Missing entry or error";
        }
     }
```

I personally think that while this may work, it's not the cleanest way of doing things.
I keep my viewmodels as clean and simple as possible, so basically just a bunch of properties with `{get;set;}` behind them.

**How are you setting the other properties in this viewmodel?**

Is there any reason why you cant just set the `StaffMemberName` the way you set the `StaffMemberId` for example?

I would personally keep all logic (apart from `DataAnnotations` etc) out of the viewmodel.
A step better would be to put your logic inside your controller methods.
Even better, would be to put in an extra layer, where you do all the database retrievals.

In that way, the controllers and the view are kept as simple as possible.

What I would do in your case is the following, I would create a MemberService like this:

```
public class MemberService
{
public string GetStaffMemberById(Guid Id)
{
    var db = new ObservationTrackerContext();
    var staffMember = db.StaffMembers.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StaffMemberId == StaffMemberId);return staffMember != null ? staffMember.FullName : "Missing entry or error";    
    return staffMember;
} 
}
```

then, in the controller, set the viewmodel:

```
public ActionResult GetInformation(Guid id)
{
var vm = new StaffMemberViewModel();
vm.StaffMemberName = memberService.GetStaffMemberById(id);
return View(vm);
}
```

in this way, your viewmodel can just change to

```
public string StaffMemberName {get;set;}
```

edit: i was focusing more on the database retrieval aspect inside the viewmodel, but @Miller Koijam also made a good point, to encapsulate these different models into a composite viewmodel.

edit number 2: You seem to be returning pure database objects, which is not really maintainable in big projects. You should "convert" or "project" these database objects into viewmodels.

[this link gives a pretty good explanation on how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432246/creating-a-mvc-viewmodels-for-my-data/15436044#15436044)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think I might be able to remove this logic into a separate class - I like the idea of putting it into the controller.  In your example you refer to `StaffMemberViewModel` being returned as the view - what I'm trying to achieve is in the `Observation` view - simply looking up the name of the `StaffMember` whose name matches the GUID already recorded in the database against this `Observation`.

Comment: how/where are you setting/filling your current Observation viewmodel?

Comment: Within my controller I have the following (this is an entity framework code first app - my first): `private ObservationTrackerContext db = new ObservationTrackerContext();

        //
        // GET: /Observation/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Observations.ToList());
        }`

Comment: `public ActionResult Index() { Return View(db.Observations.ToList());     }` - can't get the formatting quite right in the comments.

Comment: hmm kay, what you are doing is returning your "pure" database return values, which is also not really a best practice. I would try to make a seperate composite viewmodel, like @Miller Koijam said. Put your database code in a separate class, and fill your viewmodels with data from your database, and then return that, instead of the pure database objects.

Comment: OK - so business logic layer to handle db interactions, server side validation etc., then controller to interact with the bll, and model and view to handle definition and presentation of the data? Does sound like the pattern I ought to be using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432246/creating-a-mvc-viewmodels-for-my-data/15436044#15436044
this guy pretty basically explains what i'm trying to say. it's kinda hard to explain in these comments, but that link should give you a nice idea. And to react to your last comment, yes, that sounds good! :)

Answer (score 2):

The best thing is to separate each model in different class.
if there is one to one relationship, then your model is quite ok.
you can have a method called something like

```
GetStaffMemberById(Guid Id)
{
     //Add your code to fetch the StaffMember
}
```

if there is one to many relationships than
you need to show association of two models in bigger model, you can use composite model called StaffMemberObeservation/OberservationStaffMember as the associativity of parent- child. 
if your StaffMember has more than one Observation than

```
public class StaffMemberObeservation
{
public Observation { get; set; }
public IList <StaffMember>{ get; set; }
}
```

if your Observation has more than one staff members than

```
public class ObersavtionStaffMember
{


   public Staff Member{ get; set; }
   public IList <Observation> { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I think this may be the way I should be going with this. One `StaffMember` can have multiple observations. I was hoping to keep this to a more simple structure as all I really need to do is look up the name of the `StaffMember` whose GUID is already recorded against the `Observation`.

Comment: If should be IList<Staff> instead of <IList>. The same goes to Observation.